# Why $\lvert x \lvert < 2$ in this proof of $\lim_{x \to 1}x^2=1$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Why $\lvert x \lvert < 2$ in this proof of $\lim_{x \to 1}x^2=1$?

> $\lvert f(x)-L \lvert < \epsilon  \\
> \lvert x^2-1 \lvert < \epsilon \\
> \lvert (x-1)(x+1) \lvert < \epsilon \\
> \lvert (x-1)\lvert \lvert(x+1) \lvert < \epsilon$
>
> $\implies \lvert x+1 \lvert < \lvert x \lvert +1 \\
> \lvert (x-1)\lvert \lvert(x+1) \lvert< \lvert (x-1)\lvert( \lvert x\lvert +1) < \epsilon$
>
> since $\lvert x-1 \lvert < \delta \implies \lvert x \lvert < 2$
>   so $\lvert x \lvert +1 < 3$

I left out the rest of the proof, because my main question is why $$\lvert x \lvert < 2$$

Comment: Pretty sure you have a typo there, since $\lim_{a\to1} x^2 = 1$ doesn't make sense (you have an $a$ instead of $x$ there).

Comment: @ Charalampos Filippatos Thanks, just corrected.  would you be able to tell me the reason?

Comment: if $\delta<1$ then $-1<x-1<1 \rightarrow 1<x<2$

Comment: We are always free to impose restrictions on what $\delta$ we choose in the end. The important part is that we can find _some_ $\delta$, and restricting the area we search might make it easier to find. Placing such restrictions lets us have more control over how the function behaves in the region we're interested in (for instance, $x^2$ gets steeper and steeper, and that is an unnecessary complication, so we cut it off before it gets too steep). It's not unusual to declare something to the effect of "no matter which $\delta$ I choose, it shall never be larger than $1$" to achieve this.

Comment: This is a very bad written proof.

Comment: @Jack I apologize, I didn't really wrote the whole thing up, since I was just hooked by the idea, which has already been explained well by Arthur and R.MCM. but thanks!

Comment: @Tmm Exactly what they said upwards, it's just the $δ$ you choose, so in your case, it's $δ<1$.

Comment: @Tmm: No worries. I thought the proof was from some bad written book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common technique. If you want to force $|x| < n$ when choosing $\delta$ then you need $-n < x < n$. Now subtract $c$ to get $$-n - c < x - c < n - c.$$
Thus if you can force $x - c$ to be between $-n - c$ and $n - c$ then $|x| < n$. All you need to do this is take $m = \min\{|-n - c|, |n - c|\}$ and $|x - c| < m$ then

$$ -n - c \le -m < x - c < m \le n - c$$

hence $|x| < n$.

---

In your specific case: $n = 2$, $c = 1$ and hence $m = \min\{|-2-1|,|2 - 1|\} = 1$. Thus if $|x - 1| < 1$ you have

$$ -2 -1 \le -1 < x - 1 < 1 \le 2 - 1$$

and now add $1$ to get

$$ -2 \le 0 < x < 2 \le 2 $$

so in particular $|x| < 2$.